# App icon is different in Start Menu search

Tags: xaml, uwp, icons, uwp-xaml, appicon

I was developing an UWP app. I changed the app icon. **All app icons (taskbar, start menu, desktop shortcut) are changed. But Start Menu search icon is not changed.** It is showing previous icon which is currently not present in the project.

I am using "Visual Studio 2019 Professional" for development & generated app icons from Visual Assets as described here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos). Except the generated icons there is no other icons in "/Assets/Images/TileLogo" folder.

After searching in google I found that File Explorer cached old icon & it's showing old icon from cache. But there is no proper solution to clean the cache or prevent this caching.

**How can I prevent the caching or clean the cached icon and show new icon in Start Menu search?**

Comment: Well, this behavior is controlled by the system and the UWP app could do nothing with it. A possible workaround is to uninstall the app and reinstall it to refresh the cached icon.

Comment: I tried several times uninstall & install but not solved. Can you please give me any MS-Docs link/reference where it is said that "It is handled by system and UWP app can't handle it" ?

Comment: What about rebooting your device after uninstalling the app. Then reinstall it. This is a system feature. UWP does not have such an API that could control the file explorer feature like cache the icon.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem.  Did you ever find a solution?